# Importing a MySQL InnoDB dump without locking tables

Tags: import, innodb, mysql, restore

What options do I have for importing a MySQL table using the InnoDB engine, where the table already exists, without losing read access to the existing table? Generally I am referring to situations where `ALTER TABLE` is really slow, and I instead want to dump the table, modify the dump, then import it.

If I use `mysqldump` to make the dump, then when I reinsert it drops the table before inserting, so read access is of course lost until the import is complete.

Can I simply change the tablename in the dump, import that, then when that's done, drop the old table and rename the new one? Is there a better way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your table is of the same structure, I don't see any problems. You need just to skip "DROP TABLE" operator. Almost all dumpers have the option to not include DROP TABLE/CREATE TABLE in the dumps. Personally I'd recommend [Sypex Dumper](http://sypex.net/en/).

If you want to change table structure without locking table, I think the best way is to use
[pt-online-schema-change - ALTER tables without locking them](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-online-schema-change.html)

Comment: Thanks, I will run a benchmark with Sypex Dumper. Can't go wrong for $10!

Comment: @melkamo It has free edition. And it's sufficient for most needs ;)

Answer (score 1):

use MySQL Enterprise backup for this http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/backup.html